# Get specific object field within a range

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List os complex types, let's say

```
public class Point {
    public double X;
    public int    Id;
}

List<Point> points = (...);
```

How do I get a `List<int>` of all the `Id`'s within a given range with LINQ, say `(minIndex, maxIndex)`?

I could get all the point objects with `points.getRange(minIndex, maxIndex - maxIndex)`, but how can I get a list of the `Id` fields only?

Comment: as I see from the use of `GetRange` you are interested in the index of the `Point`s and not in the value range of the ID's ?=! Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want the Id you can use the [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) statement as follow:

```
var ids = points.getRange(minIndex, maxIndex - maxIndex)
                .Select(x => x.Id)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
var ids = points.Where(x => x.Id >= minIndex && xId <= maxIndex)
    .Select(x => x.Id)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ids = points.Where(p => (p.Id >= minIndex) &&
                      (p.Id <= maxIndex))
                .Select(p => p.Id)
                .ToList();
```